# Phalcon csrf fail on server

Tags: php, phalcon, csrf-protection

I am using phalcon 2.0.9.

I have a login form, with csrf protection.

This is the code in the form:

```
<input type='hidden' id='token' name='{{ security.getTokenKey() }}' value='{{ security.getToken() }}' />
```

And this is the validation in the controller:

```
if(!$this->security->checkToken()) {
    // error code here
}
```

It works perfectly on localhost, butn when I upload it to the server, it always fails. I use ajax in login. After the post request, the csrf token in session is different than the token in the post.

What could cause this?

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: "...it always fails". In what way does it fail? Do you get any error messages? In the server log, for example?

Comment: $this->security->checkToken() returns false, even if I try to login after page loaded. Seems like after generate login page, the csrf changes, but I don't know where or why.

Comment: I would NOT close this question as it is hard to explain the exact error in more detail in this case. `$this->security->checkToken()` returns false when it shouldn't. OP should have mentioned that in the question, but they did in the comment above. Keep this one open, guys.

Comment: is your `crypt` service initialized with [alphanumeric token](https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/9191/checktoken-always-return-false-when-using-a-token-from-encrypted)?

Comment: inspect your browser network tab for rogue requests.

Answer (score 0):

Credit : Daniel @
https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/922/csrf-protection-not-working

Make sure you're using the latest Phalcon version on your server as well 
And either use the server configurations given by the users on the forum or move your notfound(404) action to a controller that doesn't include CSRF TokenKey & Key generation on it's view.

When there's a item favion/robot.txt/img etc that is not found on the server this hits the 404 action and you end up have the CSRF tokens regenerated.

Hope that would help.